# Facebook Public Chat on website

Tags: html, facebook, web, chat, public

I have seen on some big website **facebook public chat** (close to some video stream for example), on which *each people* who liked the Facebook page could chat publicly with the other "likers".

I mean one chat lobby (and one only), on which each likers are allowed to post. I guess that the Admin of the Facebook page is allowed to moderate the lobby.

I would like to know if there is a **specific free API** (?) for that, and how to implement it with **HTML** on a website.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ ? 
You can also look for related Q's here -
[Integrating Facebook Chat](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5052780/integrating-facebook-chat)  
[XMPP library for facebook chat](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3598900/xmpp-library-for-facebook-chat)